# Grouping cases having at least twice the same descriptors in the same order

Tags: pyspark

I have the following dataframe :

```
+--------+--------------------+
|      id|         description|
+--------+--------------------+
|14144206|(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|14144206|(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|19461601|(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)|
|19461601|(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)|
|34578543|(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|34578543|(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|45672467|(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|45672467|(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)|
|45672467|(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)|
+--------+--------------------+
```

which can be obtained with the following code :

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        (14144206, '(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)'),
        (14144206, '(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)'),
        (19461601, '(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)'),
        (19461601, '(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)'),
        (34578543, '(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)'),
        (34578543, '(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)'),
        (45672467, '(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)'),
        (45672467, '(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)'),
        (45672467, '(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)')
            ],
    ('id', 'description')
)
```

The desired output is a list of tuples (which can be of length 2, 3, up to length(description)) and where each tuple contains the id that appeared 2 times, or 3 times, or 4 times etc. in the same order in the column description. So here the output should be :

```
[(14144206, 34578543), (34578543, 45672467)]
```

The first step would be to groupBy the id and sum the description in order to get the following data frame :

```
+--------+--------------------+
|      id|         description|
+--------+--------------------+
|14144206|(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|19461601|(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)|
|34578543|(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)|
|45672467|(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)|
+--------+--------------------+
```

However, I encounter the following error when executing this instruction :

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum("description").alias("sum_description"))

Error :"cannot resolve 'sum(`description`)' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7
```

Then for the grouping task, I don't see if there is an existing function for this purpose.

For information, my real dataframe's column description is of length 35 000, and there are about 15 000 distinct id

Answer (score 0):

Not certain I am following the logic as I get a slightly different answer, but here goes:

```
# Find the cardinality of each description
description_cnt=df.groupby('description').agg(f.sum(f.lit(1)).alias('id_cnt'))
df=df.join(description_cnt, on='description')

# Group by description and count and gather the Id's into a list
df_id_grp=df.groupby('description','id_cnt')
             .agg(f.collect_list('id')
             .alias('grouped_id'))

# Filter down to count 2 and display
df_id_grp.filter(df_id_grp['id_cnt']==2)
         .select('grouped_id')
         .rdd.map(lambda x: tuple(x['grouped_id']))
         .take(20)
```

As you can see, the answer differs from yours, but I think the logic is as you described. If you can review and let me know your thoughts I will amend accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the collect_list() function which is really useful. Basically, with your code, I get, for each level of description, the list of id that have this level. I see two drawbacks : firstly, the result is too large in the sense that one condition is lacking, ie two id's are grouped if and only if they appear at least twice in two distinct groups. Secondly, the filter condition " df_id_grp['id_cnt']==2 " prevents the collection of id's who appear in groups of 3 or more

Comment: OK, will add that condition to the code when I get some free time. The second condition is unnecessary, was just trying to match the example output you gave.

Comment: My idea would be the following : for each level of description, we have the list of id having this level. I would like to take into account the following condition : for all levels of description, for all possible couples having that level, do we find this couple in another one level of description. Then the same thing for all triplet : for each level having at least 3 id, do we find this triplet in another level of description